# Cannot bind a object list into toolkit LongListSelector Windows Phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, silverlight-toolkit, longlistselector

I want to bind list of objects to toolkit LongListSelector Windows Phone 7 as what i do in Windows Phone 8. Anyone could tell my where's wrong?

Nothing show in the LongListSelector

XAML

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector Name="MyLLS">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Background="‪#‎4A6EA9‬" Height="60" Margin="2">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

Class

```
public class NewsItem
{
    public string Link { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
}


MainPage()
{
    // something already
    MyLLS.ItemsSource = new List<NewsItem> { 
        new NewsItem { Link = "http://google.com", Title= "Google Search" }
    };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not played much with WP7 ToolKit but I've managed to display list like this:

In XAML - removed Grid and added isFlatList:

```
<toolkit:LongListSelector Name="MyLLS" IsFlatList="True">
    <toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
              <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </toolkit:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</toolkit:LongListSelector>
```

In code behind:

```
ObservableCollection<NewsItem> myList = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem>();

MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    // something already
    MyLLS.ItemsSource = myList;
    myList.Add(new NewsItem { Link = "http://google.com", Title= "Google Search" });
}
```

I haven't got much time to play with the code above, but maybe it will help. I would advise to read some tutorials - [WP7 LongListSelector in depth Part1](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios), [WP7 LongListSelector in depth Part2](http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part2-data-binding-scenarios) and probably more.

Comment: Not works. I know how to bind data on Windows Phone 8, but there is a different on Windows Phone 7 (toolkit:LongListSelector) can not do the same

Comment: @iexplore I've edited my code and as I've tested it at least display List. As I've written - beacause of the lack of time - it is like this, but maybe will help a little.

Comment: Just add IsFlatList="True" and problem solved. Not need ObservableCollection instead List. Thanks for your useful help

Comment: @iexplore List or ObservableCollection depends on your code, and you are right that in simple cases List can be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do **InitializeComponent();** first in MainPage constrator.

```
MainPage()
{
    // Init method must work
    InitializeComponent(); 
    // something already
    MyLLS.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<NewsItem> { 
        new NewsItem { Link = "http://google.com", Title= "Google Search" }
    };
}
```

Comment: You could trying move dataBind to onNavigatedTo or Loaded method.

Comment: not working, i try exactly the same in Windows Phone 8, it works. But not when move to Windows Phone 7